# Sitecore Workflow and Pipelines

Tags: sitecore, pipeline

I'm trying to implement a basic Javascript confirmation box on a workflow command (e.g. "are you sure you want to edit this?"). Depending on whether a users clicks yes or no, I want to move to a different state in the workflow. Here is the code I currently have (some logic is taken out):

```cs
[Serializable]
public class ConfirmAction
{
    public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Item currentItem = args.DataItem;
        ClientPipelineArgs clientArgs = new ClientPipelineArgs();
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor", clientArgs);
    }

    protected void DialogProcessor(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (args.Result != "yes")
            {
                args.AbortPipeline();
                return;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Confirm("Are you sure you want to edit this?");
            args.WaitForPostBack();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to the Pipeline model, especially in relation to Sitecore, so I'm somewhat grasping at straws. The problem that I'm having, I believe, is that I don't have a way of getting the result back to the Workflow Pipeline, from the ClientResponse pipeline, to tell it what to do.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Using Yan's information, I eventually came up with the following solution:

```cs
public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
{
    Item currentItem = args.DataItem;
    ClientPipelineArgs clientArgs = new ClientPipelineArgs();
    clientArgs.Parameters.Add("itemID", currentItem.ID.ToString());
    clientArgs.Parameters.Add("stateID", currentItem.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value);
    Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor", clientArgs);
}

protected void DialogProcessor(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (args.Result != "yes")
        {
            Item currentItem = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(args.Parameters["itemID"]);
            currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            currentItem.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value = args.Parameters["stateID"];
            currentItem.Editing.EndEdit();                   
            return;
        }
        SheerResponse.Eval("window.location.reload();");                
    }

    else
    {
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.YesNoCancel("Are you sure you want to edit this?", "200", "200");
        args.WaitForPostBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I think this is where you can take advantage from `ClientPipelineArgs`. Let's say you add the current item ID to the parameters to pass:

```cs
public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
{
    Item currentItem = args.DataItem;
    ClientPipelineArgs clientArgs = new ClientPipelineArgs();
    clientArgs.Parameters.Add("id", currentItem.ID.ToString());
    Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor", clientArgs);
}
```

and later on when you get positive result you get it back and move to the target workflow state (explained in comments):

```cs
protected void DialogProcessor(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (args.Result == "yes")
        {
            // 1. take item ID from args.Parameters["id"];
            // 2. get item by this ID
            // 3. move item to target workflow state
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Confirm("Are you sure you want to edit this?");
        args.WaitForPostBack();
    }
}
```

This might require some minor changes (I didn't run it myself before posting), but hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi Yan, thanks for your answer. I have looked at this approach, but it is unclear to me how to control the workflow state given the Item. I got the impression that it was something I needed to do via the WorkflowPipelineArgs. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Workflow the item is in (as well as current workflow state) is just a value of an appropriate item field. So, even if you are not aware about the special API, you can always set it like any other field value. Another question is workflow action which should occur during moving an item from state A to state B. These actions won't be executed if you change the workflow state in this low-level fashion...

Comment: BTW, this is how you can attach an action to the state rather than to a command: http://sdn.sitecore.net/FAQ/Workflow/Workflow%20State%20Action.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to attach a command template to a workflow command? I feel I may be going to down to too low of a level with my implementations. I see the ClientPage.SendMessage() function, but I don't know which parameters can go into which Commands and things like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What are you going to achieve at the end?

Comment: I have a workflow command that allows people to discard a draft by means of deleting the latest version. Implementing a solution similar to the one in this thread works technically, but I've had problems with the item not refreshing (say I'm on version 4 and I hit the workflow command, the version is deleted but it still shows as version 4 until you refresh the item in some way). This makes me think I'm doing the Sheer UI components in a strange way, since I'm not positive about best practices. I've seen the SendMessage command, but it doesn't seem to be working from the workbox itself.

Comment: You might want to take a look at DeleteItem workflow action in the following library: http://trac.sitecore.net/WorkflowModules. It seems to do basically the same as you'd like to achieve...